# Jquery dynamically created table rows unaligned with bootstrap table headers

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I have used the answer of the following stackoverflow question [Javascript / jQuery: How to dynamically add rows to table body (using arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30588797/javascript-jquery-how-to-dynamically-add-rows-to-table-body-using-arrays) , in order to achieve dynamic adding of table row. I also use a bootstrap theme. The adding is done correctly but the `<td>` are unaligned with the `<th>`.

My html code is the following:

```html
<div class="row" id="dynamic_table">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body center">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Header 1</th>
              <th>Header 2</th>
              <th>Header 3</th>
              <th>Header 4</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="table_body">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

While the jQuery code is the following:

```
tbody = "<tr><td>" + value1 +"</td><td>" + value2 +"</td><td>" + value3 + "</td><td>" + value4 +"</td></tr>";
$('#table_body').html(tbody);
```

Since I'm quite new in bootstrap framework and jQuery what should I do in order for the values to be aligned with the relevant headers?

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but you probably want to use `.append` in place of `.html` so your `tbody` is not overwritten when adding multiple rows.

Comment: We need to see your styles. If e.g. you use `display: <something other than table or table-cell>` then the whole table can become unaligned.

Comment: Peter B I just use the default bootstrap.css table styles unless you meant something else

Comment: What are some examples of the values `value1`, `value2`, etc?

Comment: @dk13 can you check my answer. and let me know.. i have used bootstrap css and added dynamic values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```js
/*for testing dynamic values */
var testData = [1,2,3,4,5];

$.each(testData,function(index, value){
var tBody = '<tr><td>row-'+value+'</td><td>row-'+value+'</td><td>row-'+value+'</td><td>row-'+value+'</td></tr>';
$('#table_body').append(tBody);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style> td,th{border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align:top;} tr{margin:0;}</style>
<div class="row" id="dynamic_table">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                          <div class="panel-heading"> Dynamic Table
                          </div>
                          <div class="panel-body center">
                             <table class="table">
                             <thead>
                               <tr>
                                 <th>Header 1</th>
                                 <th>Header 2</th>
                                 <th>Header 3</th>
                                 <th>Header 4</th>
                               </tr>
                             </thead>
                             <tbody id="table_body">
                             </tbody>
                           </table>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: If you use `.html` you get the same result, and from the looks of it you didn't change any of OP's original markup, so this is not a helpful answer.

Comment: Considering that he wanted to add it one by one or inside a `for` loop, the `.html()` it will overwrite the elements inside the `<tbody>` ending up to just one new `<tr>` with `<td>`s, but if you would use `.append()` it will add up. So I suggest also to use `append` if that is the case.

Comment: @lourz_yan i already used `append`  not `html` to add new how dynamically

Comment: Oh sorry I'm talking to @J.Titus.

Comment: @lourz_yan If you look at the OP's question, they are already using `.html`. You can also see that I commented on OP's question stating that `.append` was a better option. I was merely stating that this answer provides no further assistance to OP's problem of the data not lining up with the headers.

Comment: @swapnilnax Thanks a lot for your help, it worked fine.